# How to apply Mean Square Error row-wise in Python using NumPy without looping

Tags: numpy, matrix, neural-network, rowwise, mean-square-error

I'm building a primitive neural network to emulate AND gate. The loss-fucntion is MSE:

```
def mse(predicted, desired): 
    return np.square(np.subtract(predicted, desired)).mean()
```

In the following there are a **prediction**, and the **desired** outputs (a.k.a. labels):

```
predicted = np.array
    ([[0.5000, 0.5000],   # 0 AND 0
      [0.4721, 0.5279],   # 0 AND 1
      [0.3049, 0.6951],   # 1 AND 0
      [0.3345, 0.6655]])  # 1 AND 1

desired = np.array
    ([[1, 0],   # False
      [1, 0],   # False
      [1, 0],   # False
      [0, 1]])  # True
```

Each row (in both of the above matrices) indicates a single case. I want to keep all the cases to be held together like this, rather than splitting them into vectors. The catch is, I need to treat each row individually.

I'm trying to get the following result, but yet I couldn't:

```
returned output = 
    [0.2500,  # 1st CASE ERROR
     0.2786,  # 2nd CASE ERROR
     0.4831,  # 3rd CASE ERROR 
     0.1118]  # 4th CASE ERROR
```

I tried the following function...

```
np.apply_along_axis(mse, 1, predicted, desired)
```

but it didn't work because **"desire"** is being passed as the whole matrix, rather than a row at a time. So, is there any way to achieve that without changing "mse function" implementation or loops?

Comment: `np.square(np.subtract(predicted, desired)).mean(1)` or `((predicted-desired)**2).mean(1)` which is more IMO.

Comment: @DavidHoffman kindly consider posting this as an answer, so tha OP can accept and question does not appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all your data is in nicely formed ndarrays you can make NumPy do all the heavy lifting. In this case you can convert your `for` loop into a reduction along one of the array dimensions.

```
np.square(np.subtract(predicted, desired)).mean(1)
```

or

```
((predicted-desired)**2).mean(1)
```

which is more readable IMO.

Comment: All I needed is that single tiny digit at the end , this is amazing. this perfectly worked, **Thank you very much, sir. I do appreciate it**.